# trying to create a function based on a bool

Tags: python, sudoku

I have this thing right now, but the first part is something iffy with because the answer should be 12 because my file have 12 chapters , but i get 2726 as the answer.
I also need to make a forth function called:

`analyze_book(filename, chapter_delimiter, word)`

where the task is to use the three other functions to take in a word, calculate how many times that word is in each chapter of the book, and then plot the resaults in a graf where the x-axes is the chapternumber and the y-axes is the amount of times that word is in that chapter.
the graf is also going to look like this:

1. Title of the graf is: Amount of word shows up per chapter in filename
2. Title x-axis: Chapter
3. Title y-axis: Amount of word
4. x-axis goes from 1 to amount of chapters
5. y-axis goes from 0 to highest amount og times word +3

As said at the top, def get_chapter is a litte iffy somewhere and i dont know why
And i also lack the last function and i have no idea where to go from here.

```
def get_chapters(filename,chapter_delimiter):
    lines = None
    
    
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        
    
    num_chapters = 0
    
    
    for line in lines:
        chapters = line.split(chapter_delimiter)
        chapters = [chapter.strip() for chapter in chapters if len(chapter.strip())!=0]
        num_chapters += len(chapters)
    
    return num_chapters

print(get_chapters('alice_in_wonderland.txt', 'CHAPTER'))


def count_words(string_list, word):
    counts = []
    for string in string_list:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if string[i:i + len(word)].lower() == word.lower():
                count += 1
        counts.append(count)
    return counts

strengliste = ["Takpapp, veggpapp, papp og papir", "Papir, stein, saks og papir"]
count_words(strengliste, "Papir")


def create_number_to(number):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        lst.append(i)
    return lst
print(create_number_to(14))
```

I would appreciate any help i can get

Comment: The first answer is my code so far

Comment: please just edit your question putting in the code so far and remove it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function of count the chapters could be implemented like this:

```py
def get_chapters(filename,chapter_delimiter):
    lines = None
    
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        
    
    num_chapters = len(lines.split(chapter_delimiter))
    
    return num_chapters
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is as far as I have come on this problem** This is the writer of the questions code

```
def get_chapters(filename,chapter_delimiter):
    lines = None
    
    
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        
    
    num_chapters = 0
    
    
    for line in lines:
        chapters = line.split(chapter_delimiter)
        chapters = [chapter.strip() for chapter in chapters if len(chapter.strip())!=0]
        num_chapters += len(chapters)
    
    return num_chapters

print(get_chapters('alice_in_wonderland.txt', 'CHAPTER'))


def count_words(string_list, word):
    counts = []
    for string in string_list:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if string[i:i + len(word)].lower() == word.lower():
                count += 1
        counts.append(count)
    return counts

strengliste = ["Takpapp, veggpapp, papp og papir", "Papir, stein, saks og papir"]
count_words(strengliste, "Papir")


def create_number_to(number):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        lst.append(i)
    return lst
print(create_number_to(14))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).